# Change image path depending on screen resolution

Tags: jquery

I have working code to change image path depending on screen resolution:

```
    jQuery(window).load(function(){
      jQuery(function() {
       if(jQuery(window).width() <= 600) {
        jQuery("img").each(function() {
        jQuery(this).attr("src", jQuery(this).attr("src").replace("uploads/2013/06/", "uploads/2014/04/"));
       });
       }
       });

    });
```

But is it possible to make this work without reloading page? When I resize my browser window (for example from 1280px to 500px) it does not change image path. I will have to reload page when size is under 600px and then it works.

Comment: better use media query for this.

Comment: Are you really trying to change the source of *all* images on the page? Putting your image on a background and using CSS would be vastly simpler.

Comment: Okey. I think you are right. I was thinking that I must use <img> tags (wordpress site). But I think I can replace img with css background image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind event on load and resize:

```
 jQuery(window).on("load resize",function(e){
  jQuery(function() {
   if(jQuery(window).width() <= 600) {
    jQuery("img").each(function() {
    jQuery(this).attr("src", jQuery(this).attr("src").replace("uploads/2013/06/", "uploads/2014/04/"));
   });
   }
   });
});
```

also you can narrow down the code to replace src to:

```
 jQuery('img').prop('src', function () { return this.src.replace("uploads/2013/06/", "uploads/2014/04/"); })
```

Comment: I think if there was badge "correct answer in 90 seconds", it would be awarded a lot of times :)

Comment: @Regent:  yeah.would have been great  :)